# After angular update I keep gettin errors along the lines : Can't bind to 'xyz since it isn't a known property of 'abc'

Tags: angular

We are planning to migrate to angular 8 but when I do `npm run build` errors like : `Can't bind to 'xyz since it isn't a known property of 'abc'`come up this error did not arise in previous angular version. Here are 2 such examples :

```
ERROR in Can't bind to 'menu' since it isn't a known property of 'nb-user'.
<nb-user [ERROR ->][menu]="user_menu" [name]="userProfile.name" [picture]="userProfile.picture" [showInitials]="true" [s")


ERROR in Can't bind to 'thumb-label' since it isn't a known property of 'mat-slider'.
[ERROR ->][thumb-label]="thumbLabel"
```

Component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core'
import { NbMenuItem, NbMenuService, NbSidebarService, NbThemeService } from '@nebular/theme'

import { MENU_ITEMS } from './sidebar.menu'
import { NbMenuInternalService } from '@nebular/theme/components/menu/menu.service'
import { LoginStatus } from '../../../globals/loginData'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss'],
  providers: []
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  menu = MENU_ITEMS;
  userProfile: any;
  constructor (private themeService: NbThemeService, private ls: LoginStatus, private sidebarService: NbSidebarService) { }

  user_menu: NbMenuItem[] = [
    {
      title: 'Logout',
      link: '/admin/logout'
    }
  ];

  ngOnInit () {
    try {
      this.userProfile = this.ls.orgDataLs.user_profile.google_profile
      console.log(this.userProfile.name)
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e)
    }
  }

  toggleSidebar () {
    this.sidebarService.toggle(true, 'menu-sidebar')
    return false
  }
}
```

what do I do ? Is there a general way to solve this type of problem

Comment: Are you using the @Input decorator on your component properties?? A detailed example of a component with the issue would help

Comment: @YerkoPalma No not using it

Comment: @YerkoPalma Updated the component file also, But in angular 5  this worked withot `@input ` decoractor

Comment: Another thing. You are declaring `menu` property in HomeComponent, but the error said that you are using it in nb_user component. That seems wrong

Comment: Are you sure you are using the components properly? I just looked at the API for [nb-user](https://akveo.github.io/nebular/docs/components/user-avatar/api#nbusercomponent) and [mat-slider](https://material.angular.io/components/slider/api). The input props you provide do not match the props in the respective API. mat-slider lists thumb-label as `@Input() thumbLabel: boolean` and there is no `menu` in nb-user.

Comment: Any resolution? I tried using `@Input`. Didn't work for me. I am using Angular 5. @john can you share the dependencies of the project when you were working on Angular 5? It might be helpful. I suspect there might be changes in the Nebular APIs which may be causing these issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the `@Input` decorator. This tell angular that this particular property can be binded in your template. Import it from @angular/core

*Adding only relevant parts.*

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss'],
  providers: []
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input()
  menu = MENU_ITEMS;
  @Input()
  userProfile: any;
  constructor (private themeService: NbThemeService, private ls: LoginStatus, private sidebarService: NbSidebarService) { }

  // ...
}
```

Comment: Is this @input decorator specific to angular 8  this code worked fine in angular 5 ?

Comment: Not sure what version of angular introduced the decorator. I'm using it since version 7 and was needed then.

Comment: Its been there since angular 4

Comment: I had an error, Input is a function so add it like this `@Input()`

Comment: Yeah I added it as `@Input() `

Answer (score 1):

Your nb-user component should have "menu" as input property as it is listening for bindings.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'child-component',
    templateUrl: 'child-component.component.html'
})
export class childComponent{
    //added Input decorator over menu props
    @Input() menu: string;
}
```

Comment: thanks for reply, so is this @input decorator specific to angular 8 this code worked fine in angular 5 ?

Comment: I have worked with angular 5 too, input decorator was there.

Comment: yeah its there then this error should also come when I build in angular 5 but it does not come